# jQuery post is pending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

When a user drops multiple images on a 'drop zone' in one of my pages, I use jQuery to loop through the files in evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files and upload each of the images using a jQuery post call. This was working fine up until a few days ago, but it has since stopped working. Now only one or two of the post calls succeed, the rest end up stuck in a 'pending' state. The jQuery call I'm using is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  contentType: "application/json",
  processData: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(dbResp, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if(obj.type == 'imageAttachment') {
    return ctx.insertNewImage(dbResp);
  }
  ctx.insertNewFile(dbResp);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
  var msg = 'Error(s) were encountered during file upload: ';
  msg += jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText;
  notify(msg, 'error');
});
```

My server (nodejs) sends a 200 response back with a JSON object that contains information about the attachment document. I can see the response in Chrome's browser console, so I know it is being received, but the pending ajax post requests stay pending. Any idea on where I'm going wrong? Here's the response:

```
console.log('arguments: ', arguments);
0: Object
_id: "e4f4b9e80a9866c5efc728d00a8568ba"
_rev: "1-5dce4437e45dc030ace54f25a75de34a"
1: "success"
2: Object
```

Comment: what do you mean by `obj.type` inside callback func which is the first argument of `done()`? and what kind of information indicates that your POST request in *pending* status? you've already got success response

Comment: obj is a parameter passed to the enclosing function that makes the ajax call. I'm using the 'network' tab in Chrome's developer tools to watch the traffic. The first one or two ajax post's are successful, and the remaining posts say 'pending' in the 'Status' column. They do not resolve to an actuall http status, so it appears the post does not actually fire. The controller method on my server is not invoked more than the number of successful post's either.

Comment: This turned out not to be a jQuery issue at all. I updated nodejs from version 0.10 to  to 0.10.8 and the problem went away. Thanks anyway!